# How to pass custom certificate in post man?

Tags: curl, ssl-certificate, postman, docker-swarm

I have created a cluster in my machine which is secured with TLS certificate. Now I need to get the information via postman using TLS Certificate.

How do I pass my certificates in postman?

my working Curl Command : curl https://<"IP-Address">:2376/images/json --cert cert.pem --key key.pem --cacert ca.pem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to settings icon -> settings -> Certificates  -> Add certificates

Enter the following information

```
Host   https://<"IP-Address">:2376

CRT file location

Key file location

Passphrase
```

And then run your docker API

```
https://<"IP-Address">:2376/v1.24/images/json
```

you will get the JSON output

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the hint! I wonder how can Postman handle this request without passing cacert while in Linux shell *curl* cacert is required?

Comment: @udit-joshi How can you set --cert "cert.pem" ?